# Expo not publishing

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to publish my Expo apps, it seems to have problems with apps that have un-optimized assets. I try to run `expo optimize` on these but sometimes I [can't get this to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979112/package-failing-to-be-found-after-successful-install/56979267?noredirect=1#comment100516789_56979267) so I try publishing anyway, from the browser console, and it never finishes. I tried this earlier today and it got through `Optimizing assets...` in the publish process, and then go stuck on `Building Javascript Bundle`. Right now I'm trying again and it appears to be stuck on `Optimizing /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/ELECTRO/assets/electro-icon-1024.png`.

Even with this un-optimized asset I can get through `expo build:ios` without any apparent problems.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. Could not publish from the web console.

I am using: **Expo SDK 35, expo-cli 3.1.0**

I managed to publish the app from the command line at my project root.

first, run:

```
expo optimize
```

second run:

```
expo publish
```

When the process finishes, the cli will then output an URL that you can visit to check the published app.

Something like this:

```
https://exp.host/@profileUsername/appName
```

I hope this helps.