# scss-bundle command not found

Tags: npm, sass, bundle

I did install `scss-bundle` globally with `npm install scss-bundle -g` on Mac but when I'm running the command `scss-bundle -e ./projects/primeng-lib/src/style/_styles.scss -d ./dist/primeng-lib/style/_styles.scss,` I'm getting error `bash: scss-bundle: command not found`

Comment: Did my answer make sense / were you able to get it working?

Comment: @Nathan, look like this may help, just do not have time to check, thanks anyway.

Comment: ahh I see, more so a question just to ask a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because your npm prefix value isn't located on your system's `PATH` environment variable. The prefix will display the directory where your globally installed modules are to be installed.

Perhaps you could try the following and seeing if this helps:

1. Look up the value of your [npm prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix.html) environment variable:

   `npm prefix -g`
2. Check the value of your system's `PATH` environment variable and ensure your `npm prefix` location from step 1 is located within this path:

   `echo $PATH`

If this prefix location isn't on your `PATH` environment variable you've two options to resolve this issue:

1. Adjust your system's `PATH` environment variable, within your `.bashrc` file, to add the prefix location given in step 1 from the prior section. Something along the lines of:

   `export PATH=$PATH:<path_to_npm_prefix>
    source ~/.bashrc`
2. Adjust your npm prefix to point to a location where your system's path environment is already looking then reinstall `scss-bundle`, something along the lines of:

   `npm config set prefix /usr/local
    npm i -g scss-bundle`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Now npm prefix is in PATH `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/andreyshedko/.npm-global` and npm prefix equal to `/Users/andreyshedko/.npm-global` but still the same error.

Comment: try giving it a fresh install now: `npm i -g scss-bundle`